# How to use a for loop to set an array between certain numbers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to set an array's slots using a `for` loop to be between specific numbers.  For example, I want `slot[0]` to be set to `12` and `slot[39`] to be set to `52`, and I want every slot between to be `slot[0]` and `slot[39]` to every number between `12` and `52`; so it would be `slot[0] = 12, slot[1] = 13, slot[14] = 14`...etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is this what u want...`for(int i=0,j=12;i<=39;i++,j++)
    {
      arr[i]=j;
    }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

declare the int array anf assign the value to it using for loop
try the following code

```
int[] slotarray = new int[40];
        int valueOfFirstSlot = 12;
        for(int slotCounter = 0; slotCounter<slotarray.length; slotCounter++, valueOfFirstSlot++){

            slotarray[slotCounter] = valueOfFirstSlot;

        }
```

Comment: Hmm, the less obvious use of multiple increment statements in one `for` loop is not as readable to me compared to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] slot = new int[40];
for(int i = 0; i < slot.length; i++) {
    slot[i] = 12 + i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `12` to your loop index and set that value in the array?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
{
    slot[i] = i + 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Warning not tested:

```
for (int i = 0, num = 12; i < 40; i++, num++)
  slot[i] = num;
```